# Suppress Facebook timeline* update when adding images to an album

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on an app that creates albums in Facebook and then adds photos to the album. That side of things is working fine.

When the photos are added to the album facebook puts on the users timeline* something like " has added  new photos to the album ."

What I would like to do is suppress this message, or at least customize it a little.

Does anyone know if this possible with the Facebook API? I have not been able to find anything in their doco, and suspect it is a automated thing that facebook doesn't give control over, but would like to get confirmation.

Cheers!

*not 100% sure if this is strictly the "timeline" or just their wall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the no_story = 1 parameter.

```
$newphotodata = array(
'access_token' => $fanPageAccessToken,
'message' => $message,
'no_story' => 1,
'aid' => $albumId,
'image' => '@' . $picturePath);
$uploadedphoto = $facebook->api('/' . $albumId . '/photos/', 'post', $newphotodata);
```

I am working on this topic myself at the moment. This is my latest on it: http://facebookanswers.co.uk/?p=322

Incidently, have you worked out a way to generate a proper timeline post when you create a new album. If you do it manually, you get a nice post showing four of the images. But if you use the API you cannot get that. You can nearly get it by posting to /links/ but its still not quite right, as friends will just see a single icon.

Comment: Thanks, good find. Here is a post on the Facebook developers blog about the subject: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/482/

Comment: And in answer to your question, I haven't attempted to generate a proper timeline post yet. Would be interested in hearing a solution if you find one.

Answer (score 0):

Well, looking at the facebook api I can find no mention of how to suppress these automated status updates. From this I have concluded that it is not possible to modify or suppress these status updates.

Thinking about it some more I can understand why facebook would not these messages suppressed or changed as it could be abused by apps to make posts without a user noticing.

Answer (score -2):

Just close the window after uploading and open again IE.

Comment: The question is about using the `Facebook API`, not using a crappy browser like IE